# jqgrid filtertoolbar not working, search dialog is ok

Tags: php, jqgrid

i have a jgrid setup and displays data correctly. I ve added a filtertoolbox but when i type something the grid goes not show any data. If i use the magnifying glass to search, everything works as expected.

Here is the code:
index.html

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>blablabla</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
         <?php
         include("dbconfig.php");
         ?>


        <script src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){ 
          $("#list").jqGrid({
            url:'example.php',
            datatype: 'json',
            colNames:['Edit','ID','Alliance Name','Player', 'Level','Might','City 1','City 2','City 3','City 4','Notes'],
            colModel :[ 
            {name: 'myac', width:80, fixed:true, sortable:false, resize:false,search:false, formatter:'actions',
                    formatoptions:{keys:true}},
              {name:'id', index:'id', width:30,searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn']} }, 
              {name:'alliance_name', index:'alliance_name', editable:true, sorttype: 'int' ,sortable:true, search:true,searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn']}, stype:'text', width:110}, 
              {name:'player_name', index:'player_name', editable:true, sortable:true,search:true,searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn']}, stype:'text', width:80, align:'center'}, 
              {name:'player_lvl', index:'player_lvl', editable:true,  sortable:true, search:true,searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn']}, stype:'text', width:80, align:'center'}, 
              {name:'player_might', index:'player_might', editable:true, sortable:true,search:true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn']},stype:'text', width:80, align:'center'}, 
              {name:'city1_coords', index:'city1_coords', editable:true, width:80,search:true,searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn']}, stype:'text' ,align:'center'}, 
              {name:'city2_coords', index:'city2_coords',editable:true,  width:80,search:true,searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn']}, stype:'text', align:'center'},
              {name:'city3_coords', index:'city3_coords',editable:true,  width:80,search:true,searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn']}, stype:'text', align:'center'},
              {name:'city4_coords', index:'city4_coords',editable:true, width:80,search:true,searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn']}, stype:'text', align:'center'},     
              {name:'notes', index:'notes', width:150, editable:true,search:true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn']}, stype:'text',sortable:false} 
            ],


            pager: '#pager',
            rowNum:30,
            rowList:[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,100],
            sortname: 'id',
            mtype: "GET",
            sortorder: 'asc',
            viewrecords: true,
            ignoreCase:true,
            gridview: true,
            subGrid : true,
            height: "100%",
            editurl: 'dummy.php',
            autowidth: true,
            subGridUrl: 'subgrid.php',
            subgridtype: "json",


             autoencode: true,


        subGridModel: [{ name  : ['Wild 1','Wild 2','Wild 3','Wild 4','Wild 5','Wild 6','Wild 7','Wild 8','Wild 9','Wild 10'], 
                            width : [120,120,120,120,120,120,120,120,120,120]} 
            ],
            caption: 'Enemy Coordrinates',

            repeatitems: false,
            loadComplete: function(){ $('#list').setGridParam({datatype: 'json'}); 
            jQuery("#list").trigger("reloadGrid");
            }

          }); 
            jQuery("#list").showCol('subgrid');
            jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid',"#pager",{edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:true});
            jQuery("#list").jqGrid('inlineNav',"#pager");
            jQuery("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: false, searchOnEnter : false, defaultSearch: 'cn', ignoreCase: true});

        }); 


        </script>

        </head>
        <body>
        <table id="list"><tr><td/></tr></table> 
        <div id="pager"></div> 


        </body>
        </html>
```

example.php

```
        <?php 
        //include the information needed for the connection to MySQL data base server. 
        // we store here username, database and password 
        include("dbconfig.php");
        //ini_set("display_errors",1);
        // to the url parameter are added 4 parameters as described in colModel
        // we should get these parameters to construct the needed query
        // Since we specify in the options of the grid that we will use a GET method 
        // we should use the appropriate command to obtain the parameters. 
        // In our case this is $_GET. If we specify that we want to use post 
        // we should use $_POST. Maybe the better way is to use $_REQUEST, which
        // contain both the GET and POST variables. For more information refer to php documentation.
        // Get the requested page. By default grid sets this to 1. 
        $page = $_REQUEST['page']; 
        $limit = $_REQUEST['rows']; 
        $sidx = $_REQUEST['sidx']; 
        $sord = $_REQUEST['sord']; 

        // if we not pass at first time index use the first column for the index or what you want
        if(!$sidx) $sidx =1; 

        //array to translate the search type
        $ops = array(
            'eq'=>'=', //equal
            'ne'=>'<>',//not equal
            'lt'=>'<', //less than
            'le'=>'<=',//less than or equal
            'gt'=>'>', //greater than
            'ge'=>'>=',//greater than or equal
            'bw'=>'LIKE', //begins with
            'bn'=>'NOT LIKE', //doesn't begin with
            'in'=>'LIKE', //is in
            'ni'=>'NOT LIKE', //is not in
            'ew'=>'LIKE', //ends with
            'en'=>'NOT LIKE', //doesn't end with
            'cn'=>'LIKE', // contains
            'nc'=>'NOT LIKE'  //doesn't contain
        );
        function getWhereClause($col, $oper, $val){
            global $ops;
            if($oper == 'bw' || $oper == 'bn') $val .= '%';
            if($oper == 'ew' || $oper == 'en' ) $val = '%'.$val;
            if($oper == 'cn' || $oper == 'nc' || $oper == 'in' || $oper == 'ni') $val = '%'.$val.'%';
            return " WHERE $col {$ops[$oper]} '$val' ";
        }
        $where = ""; //if there is no search request sent by jqgrid, $where should be empty
        $searchField = isset($_GET['searchField']) ? $_GET['searchField'] : false;
        $searchOper = isset($_GET['searchOper']) ? $_GET['searchOper']: false;
        $searchString = isset($_GET['searchString']) ? $_GET['searchString'] : false;
        if ($_GET['_search'] == 'true') {
            $where = getWhereClause($searchField,$searchOper,$searchString);
        //  var_dump($where);

        }



         $totalrows = isset($_REQUEST['totalrows']) ? $_REQUEST['totalrows']: false;
        if($totalrows) {
            $limit = $totalrows;    
        }

        // connect to the MySQL database server 
        $db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword) or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error()); 

        // select the database 
        mysql_select_db($database) or die("Error connecting to db."); 
         if ($limit<0) $limit = 0;
        // calculate the number of rows for the query. We need this for paging the result 
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM enemy_coords"); 
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC); 
        $count = $row['count']; 


                if( $count >0 ) {
                    $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit);
                } else {
                    $total_pages = 0;
                }
                if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages;
                $start = $limit*$page - $limit; // do not put $limit*($page - 1)
                if ($start<0) $start = 0;

        // if for some reasons start position is negative set it to 0 
        // typical case is that the user type 0 for the requested page 


        // the actual query for the grid data 
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM enemy_coords ".$where." ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit"; 
        $result = mysql_query( $SQL ) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysql_error()); 

        $responce->page = $page;
        $responce->total = $total_pages;
        $responce->records = $count;
        $i=0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $responce->rows[$i]['id']=$row[ID];
            $responce->rows[$i]['cell']=array($row[ID],$row[ID],$row[alliance_name],$row[player_name],$row[player_lvl],$row[player_might],$row[city1_coords],$row[city2_coords],$row[city3_coords],$row[city4_coords],$row[notes]);
            $i++;
        }        

        echo json_encode($responce);
        // var_dump($SQL);
        ?>
```

subgrid.php

```
        <?php
        include("dbconfig.php");
        $id = $_GET['id'];

        // connect to the database
        $db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword)
        or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error());

        mysql_select_db($database) or die("Error conecting to db.");
        $SQL = "SELECT wild1,wild2,wild3,wild4,wild5,wild6,wild7,wild8,wild9,wild10 FROM enemy_coords WHERE id=".$id."";
        $result = mysql_query( $SQL ) or die("Couldnt execute query.".mysql_error());

        $i=0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $responce->rows[$i]['id']=$row[num];
            $responce->rows[$i]['cell']=array($row[wild1],$row[wild2],$row[wild3],$row[wild4],$row[wild5],$row[wild6],$row[wild7],$row[wild8],$row[wild9],$row[wild10],);
            $i++;
        } 
        echo json_encode($responce);
        ?>
```

what i m doing wrong? i m not a php expert! thanks!

Comment: What do you see in the POST of the search vs typing text in the filter box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `stringResult: false` option. It means *another format* of data as the format of [single field searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asinge_searching) which you currently use. You can just try to use Fiddler or Firebug or Developer Tools of IE or Chrome to catch the HTTP traffic. You will see that in case of `stringResult: false` option jqGrid send the data in the form

```
key=value
```

Where the `key` is the value of `index` or `name` property of the column where the filter applied. For example if the user type text "bla" in the input field over `notes` column than the parameter

```
notes=bla
```

will be found in the URL. You can use `$_REQUEST['notes']` to get it.

Because the format of data of single field searching is different from the format of `stringResult: false` I personally prefer to use `stringResult: true` format which is identical to the format of advanced searching see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aadvanced_searching#options).

Comment: I ve setted the string to true but it wont work!  If i var dump the sql query the where clause is empty, that s why i m getting empty rows. What code i must add in order to fetch the filters and the input typed? I m struggling for 4-5 hours with google but no luck...

Comment: @StathisNtonasII: If you set `stringResult: true` jqGrid send the filter as `filters` parameter to the server. So you will have to reimplement the server code which generate `WHERE` part if you decide to use `stringResult: true`. In general it doesn't matter whether you use `stringResult: true` or `stringResult: false`. It's important only to write server code which corresponds to the value of `stringResult` which you use.

Comment: @StathisNtonasII: Alternatively if you have problems with implementation of filtering of data *on the server side* you can do it on the client side. You need just add `loadonce: true` option of jqGrid and modify the server code so that it returns **all data** without paging. You need just sort the data correctly. If you have some hundred of rows or even in case of a few thousand of rows the implementation on the client side will works very good.